# Download from Google Cloud Storage Java APIs slower than gsutil

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I've been having a problem with using the Google Cloud Storage APIs in Java. All of the following happens on a GCP instance -- so this is all within Google's network. Basically, for downloading large zip files, `gsutil` is extremely fast, but Java code do a similar task is extremely slow, perhaps by a factor of 10x. For reference, this would be the equivalent gsutil command.

```
gsutil cp gs://mybucket/myfile.zip .
```

Pretty basic, no crazy options. However, the Java code that should do more or less the same thing is far, far slower:

```
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("myfile.zip");
        Storage.Objects.Get get = storageService.objects().get("mybucket", "myfile.zip");
        get.setDisableGZipContent(true); //Seems to have no effect
        MediaHttpDownloader downloader = get.getMediaHttpDownloader();
        downloader.setDirectDownloadEnabled(true); //Seems to have no effect
        get.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(fos);
```

I don't understand why this is so incredibly slow. As a silly, but sad test to drive home the problem, I executed `gsutil` in a different terminal window while the Java code was still chugging away, and `gsutil` downloaded the same file seconds ahead of the Java code. It's just embarrassingly slow. These are the libraries I'm using from Google:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.21.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev66-1.21.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.21.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I've tried changing the options for `setDirectDownloadEnabled()` and `setDisableGZipContent()` (since we're downloading a zip, it's already compressed) -- neither as any noticeable effect.

Comment: Can you quantify "extremely slow"? How many seconds does it take for you to download an object of, say, 100 megabytes? How long does it take gsutil?

Comment: I have seen as slow as 70s for 500MB. gsutil finishes in about 2-3.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main reasons why gsutil would be faster:

1. MediaHttpDownloader downloads chunks of bytes, by default [32MB](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/blob/c7421ae143c45b3e75c2bd6dcc86eba0d39bcf59/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/media/MediaHttpDownloader.java#L78) at a time.  So in between every 32MB, an extra round trip is required while the client waits for a service response.
2. gsutil, by default, splits the object up into [multiple slices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#sliced-object-downloads) and downloads each slice in parallel. This bypasses any single-stream bandwidth or connection limitations.

Since your code is internal to GCP, the network should be less of a factor (but it is still a factor).  I don't think that explains a 10x degradation, though, so it would be useful to clarify the exact transfer rates you are seeing.

Comment: 1) The direct download should attempt to download the whole thing as one request. 2) From their docs "using sliced object downloads also requires a compiled crcmod" -- I don't have this installed (I get a warning about it), so it can't be that a sliced download is happening.

Comment: I agree with 1), but I think this an App Engine restriction.  Regardless, especially since sliced downloads are not being used, this doesn't explain such a huge difference in performance.

Comment: Which point are you referring to (there are differing "second points" in both the answer and the comments), and why is it wrong?